# How do I change foreground color of a button when clicked?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have something like this:

```
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Margin="100,0,98,0">
                                <Button x:Name="BtProd"
                                   Content="{Binding Produto}"     
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                                   Foreground="{Binding Color}"
                                   Click="BtProd_Click">
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
```

How do I change the text color of a button in the C# .cs file?

```
   private void BtProd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    ?
    }
```

I'd like to change from white to lightgray when user clicks the button.
Thank You.

Comment: Change the "Pressed" `VisualState` in the `Button` Style Template accordingly. If I remember correctly WP doesn't support Style Triggers, and there's no reason to set a UI interaction in code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(sender as Button).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using a style trigger like so:

```
       <Style x:Key="ButtonPressStyle"
               TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            Red
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Then you define your button like so:

```
                            <Button x:Name="BtProd"
                               Content="{Binding Produto}"     
                               FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                               Foreground="{Binding Color}"
                               Style="{StaticResource ButtonPressStyle}"
                               Click="BtProd_Click">
                            </Button>
```